# Does normal authentication occur before userSession.onBeforeLogin event?

Tags: plugin-development, users

I'm trying to take advantage of the `userSession.onBeforeLogin` event to interrupt the normal Control Panel login (/admin/login) so that I can first authenticate the user against an LDAP server. However, in my testing it seems that Craft runs its own authentication prior to `onBeforeLogin` event.

```
class AdminAuthPlugin extends BasePlugin
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        craft()->on('userSession.BeforeLogin', function (Event $event) {
            if (craft()->request->isCpRequest() == true) {
                $event->performAction = false;
                exit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Using the above example, attempting to log in with a known username (with correct password) who has access to the CP, `UserSessionService` throws an error--which I expect to see due to the `exit()`: "An unknown error occurred." However, if I try to log in with the same username and an invalid password, `UserSessionService` throws the standard error, "Invalid username or password", which indicates that `onBeforeLogin` has not been executed.

Am I correct to understand that the `userSession.onBeforeLogin` event indeed fires after the default authentication attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [onBeforeLogin event](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/services/UserSessionService.php#L572) is fired after the username/password is already authenticated, but before the actual authenticated session is started, which is why you're seeing the behavior you're seeing.

For the same reason that you wouldn't expect the `onBeforeSaveEntry` event to be fired before entry validation has occurred.

I believe to pull off what you're looking for, we'd need to add a new event... something like `onBeforeAuthenticateUser`.

Probably worth adding as a [feature request](https://feedback.craftcms.com).